# PyQt4.QtWebKit and rendering multiple websites

Tags: python, pyqt

how can I render multiple pages with QtWebkit and process each one with custom python code?

for now I have:

```
class FetchThumb(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.web = QWebView()
        self.app.connect(self.web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), self.loadFinished)

    def fetch(self, url, options, callback):
        self.options = options
        self.url = url
        self.callback = callback
        self.web.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def loadFinished(self, status):
        print "URL %s loaded, status is ok? %s" % (self.url, status)

        # do something with result...

        # exit event loop
        self.app.quit()
```

and I'm calling it once:

```
fetcher = FetchThumb()
fetcher.fetch(args[-1], options, callback or default_callback)
```

works. But if I want to use "fetch" again, Qt doesn't respond anymore. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In `loadFinished` you call `self.app.quit()`. This causes the event loop to be stopped whenever the first page finished loading. A workaround would involve not calling `self.app.quit()` until you are done with all pages.